# Is this Hacking With Swift test result wrong? (While loops)

Tags: swift, while-loop

This **while loops** exercise asks if the following code will print 5 lines of code.

```
var number: Int = 10
while number > 0 {
    number -= 2
    if number % 2 == 0 {
        print("\(number) is an even number.")
    }
}
```

**According to Hacking With Swift, the correct answer is that it does print 5 lines of code.**

But the value of 'number' decreases by 2 each time and is supposed to stop the loop at 2 at which point 'number' is divisible by 2 with no remainder. Right?

ChatGPT explains this as the loop executing a total of 5 times, while only 4 lines of code will be printed.

Can anybody explain this further in simple terms? I'm quite a noob, and this confused the heck out of me

Comment: Did you test the code? I've got 8, 6, 4, 2, 0 printed, so 5 prints. When it's 2, it becomes 0, then the print is done, and then you don't pass the check of the while loop and continue after the while.

Comment: It looks like you forgot about 0. I got 5 lines of code

Comment: `0 % 2 == 0` is true, so I don't see how the 5th line won't be printed.

Comment: Run the code in a debugger so you can see what actually happens and what the value of `number` is at each step. You'll learn far more doing that than reading someone's explanation.

Comment: Work though the code yourself.  You'll never gain expertise if you just rely on a LLM. The programmer of the future will still need to understand how to code so they can tell when the AI is wrong ;-)

Comment: "so they can tell when the AI is wrong" ie, they didn't give enough explanation of what they wanted, indeed, missing specs, as we are often crying about them, we might be the next to give not enough specs.